VS Code Devcontainer Browser not Opening from Docker Compose port
I have a VS Code Devcontainer using Docker compose where the main service runs
a webserver on port 8080. My goal is for VS Code to open the browser with localhost and the  (variable) port number mapped to that service every time the container starts with the "onAutoForward": "openBrowser" parameter.
It worked at some point but I have not been able to recreate the correct configuration. I'm currently not exposing the port in docker-compose.yaml but setting it in .devcontainer.json using "forwardPorts":
    "forwardPorts": ["servicea:8080"],
    "portsAttributes": {
        "8080": {
            "label": "Webserver",
            "onAutoForward": "openBrowser"
            }
        }
}

I have also tried setting the port explicitly in docker-compose.yaml (tried ports and expose), removing it from .devcontainer.json but this does not work either.
docker-compose.yaml
services:
    servicea:
        ports:
            - "8080"

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the onAutoForward parameter is ignored since the port is explicitly forwarded.
Any help or example of a working configuration is much appreciated. I'm probably getting confused which part is handled by Docker and which part by VS Code and what exactly a automatic forwarded port in the latter is.
